# Symptom - high cpu for termsvcs and everything is extremly slow - Win2k12 server running on open stack

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, openstack, windows-terminal-services

I'm setting up win2k12r2 server on openstack but after using the server for a little while it becomes unusable. It is barely possible to move a window (e.g. the resource monitor window).

The CPU sage is high, especially `svchost.exe` (termsvcs). The virtual machine has a Intel Xeon e312xx cpu (2,79 GHz,  2 cores) and 4 GB RAM. I tried creating instances in openstack from both volumes and images. If I connect to the machine through the console in openstack it is still extremely slow so its no difference than if I use RDP.

I noticed that if I turn off the SQL services the machine becomes responsive again (SQL Server 2012 sp2)

Comment: It is still a bit weird, some software really makes the server slow. However, we found a solution regarding SQL making the server slow due to a lot of interrupts. And that is the real time clock causing issues, to change this set trace Flag 8038 which appears to switch back from interrupt timing to RDSTC. For more information:  http://www.zeninteractions.com/2011/11/08/parallels-virtualbox-using-lots-of-cpu-during-idle/